# .Net core library: How to test private methods using xUnit

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit

The latest xunit framework does not allow test runners in library code when compiled with .Net Core framework (this is allowed for normal Visual Studio code). The solution is to create a separate testing project to run your test cases.

The problem that I am having is that some methods that I want to test are 'private' methods. **How can I call those methods from my test project without making their scope 'public'?**

The more general question is: **How do you test private methods when the public method that uses the private method can not be used?** (because of its interactive nature - that is, it has a ReadLine(); contained in it)

---

**Possible solutions:**
1) Make the private methods public and rename them in a manner to indicate that they should not be used externally. (Use 'private' or 'internal' as part of the name) 
2) Create a ' public static bool Testflag' field that can be set to true in order to bypass the interactive parts of the public method to ensure testing of all its parts.

(Although I have used both of the above methods - I really do not like it because private methods should stay private and flags add a lot of extra complexities. Has someone encountered the same problem? How did you solved it?

Comment: The general answer to this question is to treat the interactive part as a service and hide it behind an interface (yours might be called `IInputRequester` or similar). Then your unit-test can pass a mocked implementation of that interface (`MockInputRequester`), while your production code can pass a real implementation of that interface (`ConsoleInputRequester`). Note that this is not just something you do for unit-testing. It's a standard part of making a [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) design.

Comment: Also looks like the public method is tightly coupled to implementation concerns that make it difficult to test. That is an indication that the design needs refactoring. (code smell)

Comment: I know this was asked a while back, but I strongly agree with RB's answer above.   When you have a class you want to test, make all its components public, and implement an interface that only shows the externally facing methods, the contract.  The interface is what other classes see, but the unit testing framework still sees the entire class.

Comment: 8.2.1 in book Art of Unit Testing 2nd edition. Only public methods (contracts) should be tests and that's it.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

A quick solution is to make `private` members that you want to test `internal`.

You can then add an `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute to your main library's AssemblyInfo.cs.  This will allow your test library (and no other library, without reflection) access to the internal methods/classes in your main library.

e.g.

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Library.Tests")]
```

Comment: And if you don't have an AssemblyInfo.cs file (which as of .NET Core 2.1, one doesn't seem to be auto-generated), then you can create one and simply add the line above and it will be picked up in your test project.

Comment: As far as I know, you can actually put that attribute anywhere in the source for your project. Theres nothing special about AssemblyInfo.cs (other than convention).

Comment: There is a typo in the code above (missing s) it should be :-

[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Library.Tests")]

Comment: @TimNewton Thanks, that's fixed now

Comment: Private methods are private for a good reason, supposedly. They should not become internal, again for a good reason. This is a way to test private methods: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60622506/538387

Comment: @BinarySolo you can add it to your .proj file create: <ItemGroup><AssemblyAttribute  Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisible"><_parameter1>"Name of Assembly to add"</_parameter1></AssemblyAttribute></ItemGroup>

Comment: Since .NET 5, you can add `<ItemGroup><InternalsVisibleTo Include="Library.Tests" /></ItemGroup>` to your roject

Answer (score 23):

For testing internal classes, [@Patric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41462971/538387) is correct.

Private methods are private for a good reason, supposedly. They should not become internal, again for a good reason.

(And some ppl argue that we should not write unit tests for private methods. Why? Well, because they are "private"! But if you are so serious to write unit tests for private methods:)

This is a much better way to test private methods:

```
public class Hello
{
  private string _firstName { get; set; }
  private string _lastName { get; set; }

  public Hello(string firstName, string lastName)
  {
     _firstName = firstName;
     _lastName = lastName;
  }

  public string HelloMan()
  {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_firstName))
       throw new Exception("Missing First Name.");
    return this.HelloMan(_firstName, _lastName);
  }

  private string HelloMan(string firstName, string lastName)
  {
     return $"Hello {firstName} {lastName}!";
  }
}
```

The test goes like:

```
public class HelloTests
{
  [Fact]
   public void PrivateHelloManShouldBeWellFormated()
   {
      // Arrange
      var firstName = "John";
      var lastName = "Doe";

      Type type = typeof(Hello);
      var hello = Activator.CreateInstance(type, firstName, lastName);
      MethodInfo method = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
      .Where(x => x.Name == "HelloMan" && x.IsPrivate)
      .First();

      //Act
      var helloMan = (string)method.Invoke(hello, new object [] {firstName, lastName});

     //Assert
     helloMan
     .Should()
     .StartWith("Hello")
     .And
     .EndWith("!")
     .And
     .Contain("John")
     .And
     .Contain("Doe");
   }
 }
```

Reference:

http://anthonygiretti.com/2018/08/26/how-to-unit-test-private-methods-in-net-core-applications-even-if-its-bad/

Comment: Although you should warn that it's not a good practice, and even in some cases, a bit risky. The rule of thumb should be "test over public methods"

Comment: I wanted to test a formula in a private method in some code I was not allowed to change and I couldn't test the public method.  Thank you for this solution!

Answer (score 3):

Old fashioned stepwise refinement makes it useful to test a private method, to the pragmatist if not the purist.

Taking @Tohid excellent answer one step further, this class can be used to invoke static or instance private methods

```
public static class TestPrivate
{
    public static T StaticMethod<T>(Type classType, string methodName, object[] callParams)
    {
        var methodList = classType
            .GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

        if (methodList is null || !methodList.Any()) 
            throw new EntryPointNotFoundException();
        
        var method = methodList.First(x => x.Name == methodName && !x.IsPublic && x.GetParameters().Length == callParams.Length);

        var output = (T)method.Invoke(null, callParams);

        return output;
    }

    public static T InstanceMethod<T>(object instance, string methodName, object[] callParams)
    {
        var classType = instance.GetType();
        var methodList = classType
            .GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        if (methodList is null || !methodList.Any()) 
            throw new EntryPointNotFoundException();
        
        var method = methodList.First(x => x.Name == methodName && !x.IsPublic && x.GetParameters().Length == callParams.Length);

        var output = (T)method.Invoke(instance, callParams);

        return output;
    }
}
```

And then used thus:

```
        {
            var result = TestPrivate.InstanceMethod<bool>(InstanceOfClass, "privateMethod", new object[] { param1, param2 });

            Assert.True(result);

            var actual = TestPrivate.StaticMethod<myReturnType>(typeof(StaticClass), "privateMethod", new object[] { param1, param2, param3 });

            Assert.True(actual.prop == expected.prop);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I think that unit testing private methods should be done only if *absolutely* needed.  I have come across a few cases where I felt it was warranted. So, here are some methods that I created in a `UnitTestBase` class I inherit my UnitTest classes from (you could also put it in a static "helper" class).  HTH

```
protected internal static TResult? InvokePrivateInstanceMethod<TType, TResult>(string methodName, object?[]? methodArguments = null, params object?[]? constructorArguments)
{
    var classType = typeof(TType);
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(classType, constructorArguments);
    var privateMethodInfo = classType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                                        .FirstOrDefault(m => m.IsPrivate &&
                                            m.Name.Equals(methodName, StringComparison.Ordinal) &&
                                            m.ReturnType.Equals(typeof(TResult)));
 
    if (privateMethodInfo is null)
    {
        throw new MissingMethodException(classType.FullName, methodName);
    }

    var methodResult = privateMethodInfo.Invoke(instance, methodArguments);
    if (methodResult is not null)
    {
        return (TResult)methodResult;
    }

    return default;
}

protected internal static async Task<TResult?> InvokePrivateInstanceMethodAsync<TType, TResult>(string methodName, object?[]? methodArguments = null, params object?[]? constructorArguments)
{
    var classType = typeof(TType);
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(classType, constructorArguments);
    var privateMethodInfo = classType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                                        .FirstOrDefault(m => m.IsPrivate &&
                                            m.Name.Equals(methodName, StringComparison.Ordinal) &&
                                            m.ReturnType.Equals(typeof(Task<TResult>)));
            
    if (privateMethodInfo is null)
    {
        throw new MissingMethodException(classType.FullName, methodName);
    }

    var methodResult = privateMethodInfo.Invoke(instance, methodArguments);
    if (methodResult is not null)
    {
        return await (Task<TResult>)methodResult;
    }

    return default;
}
```